# Image Failed to Upload Laravel 8.28

Tags: laravel-8

i get error while upload file from outside my folder images in my project. but while upload image from folder images in my project, successfull add.

please help review my code where get error.

this my code, program add image in my project :

```
 $image = $request->file('image');
    $name = time().'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
    $destinationPath = 'images';
    $image->move($destinationPath,$name);
    
    //Save to Database
    Food::create([
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'description' =>$request->get('description'),
        'price' => $request->get('price'),
        'category_id' => $request->get('category'),
        'image'=>$name
    ]);
```

getting error The image failed to upload.
[The Image failed to upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koBd8.png)

Thank you, i hope everyone can help me.